# urllib3 global default timeout value

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, urllib3

I am investigating for default value for timeout in urllib in python.
The default value for timeout is **socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT** and has Value **None**.None means Infinite timeout but what will be the minimum timeout time between retries.